# iTunes: Open Home Sharing Library by default

Tags: macos, itunes, network, music, home-sharing

On my main iMac, I've got a huge iTunes library which is shared with *Home Sharing*.

I use my MacBook much more frequently, and I have basically no music on it. I would instead like to direct iTunes to *always* open/play from the main Home Shared library if it's available.

There doesn't seem to be a setting to do this. Instead, I have to select it in iTunes whenever the computer is restarted, or the iMac goes to sleep. Is it possible to find a work-around?

I have looked around, and there are some people having resembling issues with their NAS music libraries (example: [How can I get iTunes Library to stay pointed to my NAS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30656/how-can-i-get-itunes-library-to-stay-pointed-to-my-nas)).

If my issue is effectively the same issue as automatically mounting an AFP-mounted NAS iTunes Library, there at least doesn't seem to be a consensus on how to solve this issue in 2016?

Maybe something like an AppleScript would be a solution, if there is no conventional solution. I would hope that it was possible to make iTunes look for the remote Library instead of the local one.